# How to force onboard stay on top of full screen Okular in LXDE?

Tags: lxde, window-management, kiosk, okular, fullscreen

Whenever Okular is full screen, the on screen keyboard Onboard goes behind it.

How to pin onboard on top of full screen apps like Okular?

I am using Debian LXDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution in this answer is identical to my answer in [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/1429820/124466) about the same issue in Lubuntu with LXQt. The answer turns out to be DE independent.

---

Open Onboard Settings and select "Window".
[image]
Uncheck "Dock to screen edge". Now, the "Force window on top" checkbox becomes active. Select it.

However, now onboard becomes a small window floating in the middle of the screen.
To fix it, move onboard to the bottom of the screen (or your preferred position), and resize the virtual keyboard size it appropriately.

### End results

[image]